# How to show Alert If ViewPager is scrolled beyond the last page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a viewpager with 3 fragments. If I scrolled beyond last page in view pager I need to show a toast or alert that " NO more pages available".

I have tried a lot but nothing helped me.

Any help should be greatley appreciated.

I have added the code snippet kindly go through it

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
      boolean callHappened;
      int selectedIndex;
      boolean mPageEnd;
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        selectedIndex = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if( mPageEnd && arg0 == myViewPagerAdapter.getCount()-1 && !callHappened){
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Okay");
            mPageEnd = false;//To avoid multiple calls.
            callHappened = true;
        }else{
            mPageEnd = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(selectedIndex == myViewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
        {
            mPageEnd = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to make custom view pager class for view pager

```
    public class CustomViewPagerEndSwipe extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPagerEndSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    float mStartDragX;
    OnSwipeOutListener mListener;


    public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        float x = ev.getX();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mStartDragX < x && getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
            } else if (mStartDragX > x && getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
            }
            break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
        public void onSwipeOutAtStart();
        public void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
    }
}
```

use this class in your layout xml

```
<com.utils.customview.CustomViewPagerEndSwipe
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
```

implement listener from your activity and fragment and you will get last page toast from interface

```
viewPager.setOnSwipeOutListener(this);
```

Comment: This solution is perfectly worked. Kudus to the developer.

Comment: great. Thank you

Comment: in onSwipeOutAtEnd case onPageSelected is calling twice and setting it to position 1 and I am doing some work in onpageselcted . Any solution to restrict it on position 0 only? @MohitSuthar

Answer (score 2):

Used some code from your origin code and the code from @Mohit Suthar, however, @Mohit Suthar 's answer will provide numerous alert shown if the user try to swipe before the first page( reason is because it does not use the questioner's code "callHappened" variable to avoid multiple call)

The following code does not provide perfect work if user swipe left on the upper area of the fragment. Wait for modification

And I suggested to use enum for your swiped action since it would be flexible if you have another custom logic.

```
public class CustomViewPagerEndSwipe extends ViewPager {
    public CustomViewPagerEndSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    float mStartDragX;
    SwipeAction mSwipeAction;
    OnSwipeOutListener mListener;
    boolean callHappened = false;
    public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        float x = ev.getX();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mStartDragX = x;
                callHappened = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!callHappened) {
                    if (mStartDragX < x && getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                        mSwipeAction = SwipeAction.BEFORE_START_PAGE;
                        mListener.onSwipe(mSwipeAction);
                        callHappened = true;
                    } else if (mStartDragX > x && getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                        mSwipeAction = SwipeAction.AFTER_LAST_PAGE;
                        mListener.onSwipe(mSwipeAction);
                        callHappened = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    public enum SwipeAction {
        BEFORE_START_PAGE, AFTER_LAST_PAGE
    }
    public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
        void onSwipe(SwipeAction pSwipeAction);
    }
}
```

The code you call in your activity/fragment

```
viewPager.setOnSwipeOutListener(new CustomViewPagerEndSwipe.OnSwipeOutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSwipe(CustomViewPagerEndSwipe.SwipeAction pSwipeAction) {
        switch (pSwipeAction) {
            case BEFORE_START_PAGE:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage("Swipe out start").create().show();
                break;
            case AFTER_LAST_PAGE:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage("Swipe out end").create().show();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Updated from **@Mohit Suthar**'s answer. In my case I use toast and I want to be less sensitive and want to be little less occured.

```
private final static long TIME_MS = 2000;
private final static long THRESHOLD = 50;

OnSwipeOutListener mListener;
float mStartDragX;

private boolean activated = false;
private Timer mTimer;
private TimerTask mTimerTask;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    float x = ev.getX();
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.JSC("TEST", "1 : " + (mStartDragX < x - 20 && getCurrentItem() == 0));
            Log.JSC("TEST", "2 : " + (activated));
            Log.JSC("TEST", "3 : " + mStartDragX);
            Log.JSC("TEST", "4 : " + x);
            Log.JSC("TEST", "5 : " + (x - 20));

            if (mStartDragX < x - THRESHOLD && getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                if (!activated) {
                    activated = true;
                    prepareTimer();
                    mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, TIME_MS);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
                    }
                }
            } else if (mStartDragX - THRESHOLD > x && getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                if (!activated) {
                    activated = true;
                    prepareTimer();
                    mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, TIME_MS);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    try {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private void prepareTimer() {
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activated = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with  `viewpager.canScrollHorizontally(View.SCROLL_AXIS_HORIZONTAL)` method if it returns false then you are at the last item of view pager.

Comment: This code is working when I reached last page of viewpager. I need swiping after last page.